# How can I manage items with shelf expiry in MAXIMO

Tags: maximo

We are managing some disinfection chemicals in our warehouse that have shelf expiry life.
What is the best way to manage the expiry date in MAXIMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Expiration Date and Shelf Life fields on Inventory records are not applicable to items that are not set up as LOTTED as the Lot Type in Item Master/Inventory. These fields only have functionality for Inventory records when the item has a Lot Type of LOTTED. The functionality is described below.

-On receipt of the Lotted item, the User accepts/enters the Bin number and the Lot number;
-When the receipt is complete, the User enters the Shelf Life and the Expiration Date is calculated;

Once the Expiration Date is met, and there is a Current Balance on hand, the Expired Quantity in Stock value populates with this balance and the Current Balance and Quantity Available fields re-calculate to reflect only the quantity of this item on hand that has not exceeded the Expiration Date.

Some clients have set up Escalations to be warned of lotted items that are getting close to the expiration date by defining values in the following fields in the Escalation record:
Applies To: INVBALANCES
Condition: curbal >= 1 and lotnum is not null
-Escalation Point set to: USEBY -90.00 DAYS

Note: the Expiration Date field on the Inventory record is invbalances.useby